# How can I block ads in Facebook videos

Tags: applications, video, facebook, ads, adblock-plus

I have installed AdGuard Pro and have installed all the filters.

Nearly every video I watch on Facebook (only when using my Android phone) becomes interrupted by a video ad.

In contrast, my partner also has AdGuard Pro on a Android and she experiences zero ads during facebook videos. It seems that we have the same setup, however I receive ads and she doesn't.

I have been trying to figure out how to block these ads for over 1 year.

Please help.

Thank you